# Meteor App doesn't start on Windows

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the following problem when I'm starting a created meteor app:

**Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.

Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.

Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.**

I know on Stackoverflow are many threads about this error, but nothing had helped for me. In other posts you can read, delete the files in `\.meteor\local\db` but in my app I have no files in this directory after generating.

Meteor would installed with the Windows Installer on Windows 7.

In the corresponding directory I've started the `cmd` and called the command:
`meteor create testApp`

Afterwards to start the App, I'm going in the directory `testApp` and called the command `meteor` and then it displayed the error message.